# Remote Session: Switching from Desktop to Metro Mode Windows Server 2012

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I'm having a terrible time switching back/forth between the desktop and metro mode in remote desktop windows accessing a Windows 2012 server.

I know of two ways--one doesn't work in remote session windows and the other works very, very, poorly:

1. Using the "hot zones" at the very right edge of the screen--hard to hit when the right edge of the "screen" is just the edge of a remote session window with nothing to "stop" the mouse against.
2. Press the "Start" button--brings up my PC startmenu rather than the remote session start menu.

Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To display the Start screen in your remote desktop session, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>.

Comment: +1 - Also, just going full screen is another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing Windows Logo + Q on the keyboard brings up the search menu and a list of all the apps installed on the machine, including the desktop mode........